# linking div id not working in html position i think

Tags: html, css

I am trying to link a image, this is the ID in html:

```
<div id="testimage"><a href="http://mja.co.uk/Events"></a>
```

As you can see my id is "testimage" in css I have added a background image.

How do I make this image as a link. currently its not working,.

Answer (score 1):

Put the link around the image, you should make sure the anchor is displayed as a block, because prior to HTML5, a block element wrapped inside an in-line element is invalid:

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://mja.co.uk/Events"><div id="testimage"></div></a>
```

**CSS**

```
a{ display:block; }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/VS7Hb/)

Comment: According to **[HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)**: *The `a` element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links).* So there's no need to display the anchor tag as a block-level element.

Comment: @HashemQolami It's *only* valid in HTML5. Edit made.

Comment: Thank you so much! life saver!

Comment: actually, i have a few images, i done it to the first image, and works, however when i do it to the 2nd image, the whole page changes! check link : http://mja.anytimeafter9.co.uk/

Comment: OK so rather than use `block`, use `inline-block`

Comment: that makes it worse. check now, this is inline-block

Comment: This is probably a white-space issue, make sure there is none between your `inline-block` elements.

Comment: a{display:inline-block;} used this still not working

Comment: any ideas, how can 1 line change everything